# Replace an attribute with percentage of two attributes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

As the title says, I want to compute the percentage of two attributes and replace the last attribute of a dataset with new percentages.

The dataset is as follows:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('2016-17-to-2018-19-immunizations.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

[image: Dataset]

My current attempt is:

```
enrollment = newDataset.iloc[:,7:8]
count = newDataset.iloc[:,9:10]

newDataset.iloc[:,10:11] = count / enrollment

newDataset.to_csv(r'newDF.csv', index='None')

newDataset.head()
```

But the last percentage attribute is not getting replaced with the new percentages.
[image: newDF]

Any leads what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit-1**
Dataset.csv (Showing first 5 records):

```
SCHOOL_YEAR,SCHOOL_CODE,COUNTY,PUBLIC_PRIVATE,CITY,SCHOOL_NAME,REPORTED,ENROLLMENT,CATEGORY,COUNT,PERCENT
2016-2017,52749,MONTEREY,PRIVATE,PRUNEDALE,PRUNEDALE CHRISTIAN ACADEMY,Y,10,PBE,,
2016-2017,52749,MONTEREY,PRIVATE,PRUNEDALE,PRUNEDALE CHRISTIAN ACADEMY,Y,10,HEPB,,
2016-2017,52749,MONTEREY,PRIVATE,PRUNEDALE,PRUNEDALE CHRISTIAN ACADEMY,Y,10,DTP,,
2016-2017,52749,MONTEREY,PRIVATE,PRUNEDALE,PRUNEDALE CHRISTIAN ACADEMY,Y,10,POLIO,,
2016-2017,52749,MONTEREY,PRIVATE,PRUNEDALE,PRUNEDALE CHRISTIAN ACADEMY,Y,10,Up-To-Date,,
```

Comment: From the data you've shown, you'll never know if your percentage calculation works because your count is `0`. Dividing anything by 0 will return `NaN`. Also consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of using images of your data.

Comment: @CameronRiddell Thanks but I'm dividing 0 with some value eg for first case, it is 0/10 so the answer should be "0" instead of "NaN". I hope it clarifies. With regards to dataset what sort of minimum reproducible example are you expecting. Its a csv dataset.

Comment: @CameronRiddell I added the dataset example. Hope its clear now!

Comment: Oh wow I totally misread your code. Thanks for clarifying & including some data! Though it seems your `count` column in the data you've provided is all missing? Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @CameronRiddell Count column is sparsely populated. I'm using backward fill to the values using dataset.bfill()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a trimmed version of your sample `Dataset.csv`:

|  | SCHOOL_YEAR | SCHOOL_CODE | ENROLLMENT | COUNT | PERCENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 1 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 3.0 | NaN |
| 3 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 8.0 | NaN |

You can set the `PERCENT` column like so:

```py
df.PERCENT = df.COUNT / df.ENROLLMENT
```

|  | SCHOOL_YEAR | SCHOOL_CODE | ENROLLMENT | COUNT | PERCENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 3.0 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 2016-2017 | 52749 | 10 | 8.0 | 0.8 |

Note that the `PERCENT` column already existed in this case. If the target column did not already exist (e.g., `RATIO`), then we would need to use bracket notation for the target variable (e.g., `df['RATIO'] = df.COUNT / df.ENROLLMENT`).